# 3027 "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only." after using make table from excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I can access my database through excel, the problem comes when I try to access it a second time. It seems I'm leaving something open behind me, but I don't understand what.

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strInput As String

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
strInput = Sheets("base_pivot").Range("I4").Value
'I get the input for the parameter from my sheet base_pivot on the cell I4

With con
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open "C:\cmo_accounting\CMO_accounting.mdb"
End With

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandText = "mk_edu_ana_invoices"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("[input_code_ana]", adChar, adParamInput, 5)
    .Parameters("[input_code_ana]") = strInput
End With

cmd.Execute

con.Close

Set cmd = Nothing
Set prm = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
```

This works the first time I use it, and it works again as soon as I reopen the excel file. It seems the connection is closed when excel is closed.

Comment: A couple of things I've spotted - not sure if either will make a difference though. Where have you defined `strPath`? (using `option explicit` would avoid these problems). Also `Range("I4:I4")` can simply be `.Range("I4")`

Comment: Hey, I made the change for strPath I put the string right there so it is more clear for everyone. I will make the change for the range I4. Thanks!

Comment: Where is this macro (sub or function) located and how is it triggered? Is there another database connection elsewhere in workbook?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found an answer to my question. It was linked to the queries in my excel file. When I was refreshing the data from my access file, it left the access file open. I never had the problem like this before, so I really thought it was with my vba code. What I had to do was change the connection string from "share deny read" to "share deny none".

Thanks all for your help.